# How to perform ECDH with IAIK PKCS#11 Wrapper

Tags: pkcs#11, ecdh, iaik-jce

I am trying to use IAIK PKCS#11 wrapper to perform ECDH key agreement. I can see that there is a class of the parameters: [EcDH1KeyDerivationParameters](http://javadoc.iaik.tugraz.at/pkcs11_wrapper/current/index.html). But I don't see any classes of the keys for ECDH: http://javadoc.iaik.tugraz.at/pkcs11_wrapper/current/iaik/pkcs/pkcs11/objects/package-summary.html

When running ECDH key agreement via IAIK PKCS#11 wrapper, what key types should I feed into it? Can I use ECDSA key objects or DH key objects? Or I need to something extra?

Thanks